# how to add trailing stop loss?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

i have made a stratergy for buy and long. I want to add trailing stoploss with pips. i want like 10 pips of trailing stoploss, and want to exit based of stoploss not because of trend change. After the stoploss is hit, only enter on next trend change signal weather buy or sell. no reenter once the stop loss is hit. I tried my best but could not figure out how to add trailing stoploss and no reenter condition. your help will be really appreciated.
Thank you

```
//@version=5
strategy('Supertrend MTF Heikin Ashi', overlay=true)


Mult = input.float(defval=0.5, title='ATR Factor',  maxval=100, step=0.1)
Period = input.int(defval=5, title='ATR Period',  maxval=100)
//Heikin Ashi high, low, close
h = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, 
high)
l = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, low)
c = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, 
close)
//HeikinAshi atr
Atr = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, 
ta.atr(Period))
Up = (h + l) / 2 - Mult * Atr
Dn = (h + l) / 2 + Mult * Atr
float TUp = na
float TDown = na
Trend = 0
TUp := c[1] > TUp[1] ? math.max(Up, TUp[1]) : Up
TDown := c[1] < TDown[1] ? math.min(Dn, TDown[1]) : Dn
Trend := c > TDown[1] ? 1 : c < TUp[1] ? -1 : nz(Trend[1], 1)
Trailingsl = Trend == 1 ? TUp : TDown
linecolor = Trend == 1 and nz(Trend[1]) == 1 ? color.lime : Trend == -1 and 
nz(Trend[1]) == -1 ? color.red : na


uptrend = Trend ==1 
downtrend = Trend == -1 

plot(Trailingsl, color=linecolor, linewidth=2, title='SuperTrend')

bgcolor(uptrend == 1 ? color.new(color.teal, transp = 85) : color.new(color.red, 
transp = 85))
timeallowed = input.session("0945-1100", title = "allowed time")
iswithintime = time(timeframe.period, timeallowed)



if uptrend and iswithintime  
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)

if downtrend
    strategy.close("long", qty_percent = 100)

if downtrend and iswithintime 
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short)

if uptrend
    strategy.close("short", qty_percent = 100)
```

Comment: About backtest in [heikin ashi] (https://www.tradingview.com/script/q9laJNG9-Backtesting-on-Non-Standard-Charts-Caution-PineCoders-FAQ/).

Answer (score 0):

To *trailing*, use [strategy.exit](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dexit)

```
strategy.exit(
  'Trailing Stop',
  'long',
  trail_points   = 10,
  trail_offset   = 10)
```

Comment: this one works but, I don't want to enter once stop loss is hit

Comment: it is working but I don't want to enter once stop loss is hit. any idea how to fix it?